# Linux No such file or directory despite there being a file

Tags: linux, permissions

I am trying to execute an ILI9342 driver binary, nothing fancy using `sudo /path/to/binary`.

At first it gave me a permission error, which I have fixed using `chmod +x /path/to/binary`

However, after fixing the permission erorr, it keeps giving me a not found error. (`/path/to/binary: No such file or directory`)

Output of `ls -a`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 zorb zorb 72940 May  4 21:12 display
drwxr-xr-x 5 zorb zorb  4096 May  4 20:35 fbcp-ili9341
drwxr-xr-x 9 zorb zorb  4096 May  4 20:29 Raspberry-Pi-Installer-Scripts
```

output of `file /path/to/binary`

```
display: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=a43988301ce860d3743ae1924521672e4ed665fe, with debug_info, not stripped
```

(Yes I have checked if I misspelled the path)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps better to post the actual path and file you're trying to run.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the output of `ls -l /path/to/binary` and `file /path/to/binary` if the file is text, show the first line.

Comment: Also see this answer on our sister site: [*"No such file or directory" lies…*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11008/108618)